# How to find the first entry point in java code?

Tags: java, debugging

This is regarding java debugging. there is an application which inserts something into our application.i want to know the first point of entry in the code just by debugging, i don't know how the other app inserts into our app. but this is a generic code analysis. how to do this. Please let me know if you need more inputs?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the first output from your application. It will show you the traceback from where it started. Then you can get to know where the transfer started from the other app to yours.

Comment: i am degugging a remote application and i dont have logs

Comment: How does the other app insert things into your app? Web service call? RMI call?

Comment: its just a simple TCP Protocol to insert

Comment: Please update the question, on the details you know, so we can help in a better way

Comment: If I understand it right, the outer app will be giving a TCP call to a exposed end point, you need to find the address where call is made, and find the same address in your app, there will be mechanism to expose that particular endpoint to listen for incoming requests